# how can I use python and mayavi to do texture on a surface?

Tags: python, textures, mayavi

Mayavi and python are exiting, simple and very good.
12 hours of working to do something simple: texture! I can see the plane that I'm drawing but I can't see the image on it, it's all white. here is my code: I hope that someone could help me, thank you.
the Code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
import vtk

im=Image.open('ortofoto90.jpg')

pixel_x, pixel_y = im.size
ext = [10, 20, 10, 20]

xstep = float(ext[1] - ext[0]) / float(pixel_x)
ystep = float(ext[3] - ext[2]) / float(pixel_y)     
X, Y = np.mgrid[ext[0]:ext[1]:xstep,ext[2]:ext[3]:ystep]
def f(x,y):
    return x+y
Z = f(X,Y)


surf = mlab.surf(X,Y,Z, color=(1.0,1.0,1.0))
#img = image_from_array(np.array(im))
texture_img = vtk.vtkTexture()
texture_img.interpolate=1
texture_img.input = 'ortofoto90.jpg'
surf.actor.enable_texture = True
surf.actor.tcoord_generator_mode = 'plane'
surf.actor.actor.texture = texture_img
mlab.show()
```